# How do you detect Collision between sprite and Wall to stop movement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an app in single view application. It is just a simple maze game. I want to prevent the character from moving through walls but I am unable to do this (lack of experience). Could someone please help I would really appreciate it. My code is below.

COLOR.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int CharacterMovementUp;
int CharacterMovementLeft;
BOOL CollideWithWalls;

@interface color : UIViewController{
    NSTimer *MovementTimer;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Character;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *Walls;

-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender;
-(void)Movement;
-(void)Collision;

@end
```

COLOR.M

```
#import "color.h"

@interface color ()

@end

@implementation color

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ((point.y > 460) && (CollideWithWalls == NO)) {
        CharacterMovementUp = 7;
        CharacterMovementLeft = 0;
    }
    else if((point.y < 140) && (CollideWithWalls == NO)) {
        CharacterMovementUp = -7;
        CharacterMovementLeft = 0;
    }
    else if((point.x < 160) && (point.y < 463) && (point.y > 140) && (CollideWithWalls == NO)){
        CharacterMovementUp = 0;
        CharacterMovementLeft = -7;
    }
    else if((point.x > 160) && (point.y < 460) && (point.y > 140) && (CollideWithWalls == NO)){
        CharacterMovementUp = 0;
        CharacterMovementLeft = 7;
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CharacterMovementUp = 0;
    CharacterMovementLeft = 0;

}

-(void)Movement{
    _Character.center = CGPointMake(_Character.center.x + CharacterMovementLeft, _Character.center.y + CharacterMovementUp);

}

-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
    MovementTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(Movement) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CollideWithWalls = NO;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You've tagged this with Sprite Kit, but you're not actually using anything to do with Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use this SpriteKit tutorial http://mytechspace.com/2014/02/tutorial-how-to-develop-flappy-bird-game-in-ios-using-spritekit.html

Comment: That helps me understand Collision better, but it does not tell how to stop Sprite moving through wall when collision is detected. Would you have any other helpful links?

Comment: That example shows how to handle collision between 2 bodies. That is more than enough for what you are looking for.